# If I gift money to somebody then am I doing Adhamma?

Tags: anatman

Sabbe Dhamma Anatta says

Form is not me , mine or myself.Feeling is not me , mine or myself .Perception is not me , mine or myself.Choices is not me , mine or myself.Consciousness is not me , mine or myself.

Suppose I give one million dollar to somebody then am I doing Adhamma (not Dhamma , not supporting the path of Nibbana)?

Because giving money means

Money is yours.
Feelings resulting from becoming rich is yours.
Perception of rich is you , yours and yourself.
Choices of luxurious living is yours.
Consciousness of richness or luxurious living is yours.

By giving money to somebody am I not propagating a wrong notion of Self(which in my opinion is adhamma)?

Following is link to definition of Dhamma as an answer to “[Is Anatta a phenomenon ?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/49796/11541)”

To quote :

> While the word 'dhamma' is used AN 3.136 is in relation to 'natural
> law', it is a 'dhamma' because the wisdom/understanding of anatta as
> natural law 'supports' liberation from suffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that it's keeping your money to yourself, not giving, that's more likely to be selfish -- e.g., "this is mine".

Actually in my experience, if you give money to someone less wealthy than you, then they may turn around and re-give it, to someone less wealthy than they are.

In any case all things remain anatta.
Giving "virtuously" may be an opportunity for *mudita*.

Giving money to an addict, though, or a foolish child, might not be skilful. You can  find more details (about gifting) e.g. by reviewing the topics tagged [dana](/questions/tagged/dana) for example [Question about Dana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5342/254)

Answer (score 2):

There are many motivations for giving a gift.

Most are selfish, but the best motivation for giving a gift is not selfish.

The best motivation for giving a gift is [adornment of the mind](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31371/471), which means making the mind virtuous. It's the best motivation according to [AN 7.52](https://suttacentral.net/an7.52/en/thanissaro?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false).

> “Mendicants, there are these eight grounds for giving. What eight? A
> person might give a gift out of favoritism or hostility or stupidity
> or cowardice. Or they give thinking, ‘Giving was practiced by my
> father and my father’s father. It would not be right for me to abandon
> this family tradition.’ Or they give thinking, ‘After I’ve given this
> gift, when my body breaks up, after death, I’ll be reborn in a good
> place, a heavenly realm.’ Or they give thinking, ‘When giving this
> gift my mind becomes clear, and I become happy and joyful.’ Or they
> give a gift thinking, ‘This is an adornment and requisite for the
> mind.’ These are the eight grounds for giving.”
> [AN 8.33](https://suttacentral.net/an8.33/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: Even if my intentions are pure , am I not spreading Adhamma ?

Comment: @SacrificialEquation Karma is all about intentions in Buddhism.

Comment: @SacrificialEquation I think it's doctrine that it's 'better' give to people who are (more) virtuous -- that's part of the doctrine about "merit" -- ideally to monks for example (see also "field of merit") to whom of course you wouldn't give money but only "requisites". Even when [Anathapindika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anathapindika) gave "a million dollars", those gifts were in the form of requisites, e.g. the land for a forest monastery, and meals.

Answer (score 1):

The enlightened, such as enlightened monks, require gifts. The unenlightened also require gifts. Also, gifts are required to be given when there is a natural obligation. From the viewpoint of an enlightened practitioner, none of this giving is required to be 'personal', even though the giving is required to be performed. As AN 8.33 says: "*This is an adornment and requisite for the mind*".