# Does “Sabbe Dhamma Anatta “ exclude Adhamma?

Tags: dhammas

Adhamma word is used at few places in the [Suttas](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/49826/11541). Adhamma is opposite of Dhamma. [If Dhamma means Right then Adhamma means Wrong.](https://suttacentral.net/ja457/en/rouse?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

There is a characteristic of existence: Sabbe Dhamma Anatta.

Can I say “ Sabbe Adhamma Anatta “?

Does “ Sabbe Dhamma Anatta “ exclude Adhamma? If not then how do we reconcile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Sabbe Dhamma Anatta “ incudes adhamma because the word 'adhamma' refers to 'wrong modes of practice/acting' ([refer to Thag 4.10](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/49831/8157)) where as the word 'dhamma' in '*sabbe dhamma anatta*' does not refer to '*modes of pratice*' but refers to 'phenomena' or 'things'.

The word 'dhamma' has multiple meanings dependent upon context. Refer to my old blog here: [The word ‘dhamma’ in context](https://dhammadhatu.wordpress.com/2016/06/13/the-word-dhamma-in-context/)

Note: this old blog says for Dhammapada verses 1 & 2, the word 'dhamma' means 'mental states". Currently, I am not sure about this. I now think the word 'dhamma' here means '*modes of practice/acting/living*' (which become '*doctrines*'; '*teachings*').